# Can I define the Entity Listeners in the Same Entity Class?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, entitylisteners

E.g., will the below code run properly?
Or do I have to define a separate Entity Listener for each and every entity class?

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(value = Abc.class)
public class Abc{
    ...
    @PreUpdate
    public void doPreUpdate(){
    //do something
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need the `@EntityListeners` annotation. It will work just fine with just the `@PreUpdate` annotated method.

From javadoc for `@PreUpdate`:

> This annotation may be applied to methods of an entity class, a mapped
>   superclass, or a callback listener class.

Comment: Wow, great. Thanks a lot for the precise answer !!